# Force Django to download file instead of going to link

Tags: python, django

I am using **Django** to create a web page which is populating a table using the following code in the template:

```
 {% for dog in foo %}

    <tr>
    <td> {{dog.first_name}} </td>
    <td> {{dog.last_name}} </td>
    <td> {{dog.email}} </td>
    <td><<a href =  {{dog.profile.path}}><img src="not fo.jpg"></a> </td>
    </tr>
```

The '**profile**' file is uploaded using a FileField in Django and is being correctly saved in the Media folder. But when I click on the not fo img,

> I get a Page Not Found - 404 error

The methods I have seen rely on changing the view. But my view is simply sending the objects:

```
  def DogHome(request.GET):
    DogList = dog.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'DogHome.html', {'foo':DogList})
```

What is a way in which I can ensure that the hyperlink leads to a file download/opening the file(PDF, DOC) in the browser? After upload, the file is being stored correctly in the media folder.

Comment: i see a bit of syntax gaga.. you have two less-than symbols<<a href = "..  and also your filename has a space in it .. could possibly be causing problems..  ?

Comment: Rectifying the bracket didn't fix the problem. Neither did changing the image name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. You are not quoting the attribute value (as Nick pointed out).
2. You are using `.path` - this is the path to the file on your filesystem, you need to use `.url` which is the url to the file, so that it will be downloaded.

   If `MEDIA_ROOT` is `C:\Files\`, and `MEDIA_URL` is `/media/`, and you have set the field like `profile = models.FileField(upload_to='dogs')`, then:

   `{{ dog.profile.path }}` is `C:\Files\dogs\hello.jpg` and `{{ dog.profile.url }}` is `/media/dogs/hello.jpg`.

In short, you need:

```
<a href="{{ dog.profile.url }}">
```

Comment: Hi. I tried this, the Request URL has changed to this: http://127.0.0.1:8000/portal/Dog.pdf where portal is the name of the app. But the file still doesn't download/show. It instead keeps looking for it like a URL in the urls.py and shows a 404 because no match comes up.

Comment: This is because you didn't setup your project correctly. Please read [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/file-uploads/).

Comment: Could you maybe point the direction in which I went wrong? Do I have to make a change in the urls.py to accomadate static files at this URL?

Comment: You need to read the documentation, as there are multiple steps you need to do.

Comment: Hi, I have gone through the page you linked. The files are uploading correctly to the directory I want. I am using the upload_to attribute. I am using a ModelForm and it gets saved in the directory I want it too. I don't think the problem is the uploading.

Comment: Did you go through the steps listed [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development)?

Comment: You are missing a setting; I can't guess what it is - you need to just go through the documentation and make sure you have added `MEDIA_ROOT` and it points to a valid directory; `MEDIA_URL` is set, `urls.py` is configured correctly; and then _re-upload the image_ for the object and try your view again.

Comment: Hi, the problem did end up being in the MEDIA_ROOT setting. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You are not quoting the href attribute, if there are any spaces in the path to the file name (like you have in the src of your img), then it will try to recognize another attribute of your anchor.

Comment: I did both. Not working. The problem to me seems like Django is thinking of the anchor link as a new URL. It is searching the URLs.py to find a match for the file path. I get the 404 error with this message:
`code`
The current URL, Users/me/DogVirtualSpace/DogPortal/media/Dog.pdf, didn't match any of these.
`code`

Comment: Can you show an example of the rendered html in the browser?

Comment: The 404 page shows this as the requested URL: 

http://127.0.0.1:8000/Users/me/DogVirtualSpace/DogPortal/media/Dog.pdf

I am not sure if this is the correct URL that should be fetched for the image.

Comment: That looks like the full path from the root of your system, it needs to be relative to your application, or your need to return the bytes from that file manually.  I'm not sure how to do that in python.

Comment: This is sort of the HTML page I am rendering: http://postimg.org/image/5074uzngl/